# Необходима ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

В данном предложении, требуется ли запятая перед как? Если да, то почему?

> Проголодались? У нас есть отличная идея
> как быстро и вкусно перекусить в
> течение дня.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю,запятая нужна, так как далее идет придаточное предложение (безличное)